# How to fix "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" warning?

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I'm trying to create tar.gz file but I keep getting the error 
`` tar: Removing leading `/' from member names ``
by doing:

```
sudo tar -zcf test.tar.gz /opt/stagecoach/apps/test/current/
```

Ive googled it and found the `-P` option but I still get the same error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo tar -cvzf test.tar.gz /opt/stagecoach/apps/test/current
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
sudo tar -czf test.tar.gz -P /opt/stagecoach/apps/test/current

Answer (score 0):

The path of the archive when specified causes this informational message, you can do the following to resolve it:

```
tar -zvcf /tmp/mike.tar.gz -P /tmp/mike
```

or

```
tar -zvcf mike.tar.gz -P /tmp/mike
```

or

```
tar -zvcf mike.tar.gz /tmp/mike
```

Note: it is not an error, just informational.

Answer (score 0):

Changing directory using the -C option solved the confusing message about removing leading `/' from member names:

```
tar cf - -C /working-directory .
```